# How to handle a connected bluetooth keyboard's operations in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

My `IOS` app need to handle a connected bluetooth keyboard to do some function in the app, I [tried this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446978/swift-capture-keydown-from-nsviewcontroller), but the xcode cannot found the `Cocoa`

Then I tried this method, this time xcode cannot find the `canBecomeFirstResponder` in super class.

How can I [capture keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045170/ios-swift-interrupt-keyboard-events) in my app?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var keys = [UIKeyCommand]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        for digit in "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        {
            keys.append(UIKeyCommand(input: String(digit), modifierFlags: [], action:  Selector(("keyPressed:"))))
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var keyCommands: [AnyObject]? {
        get {
            return keys
        }
    }


    func keyPressed(command: UIKeyCommand) {
        print("user pressed \(command.input)")
    }

}
```